# How do launch jar through javaw.exe with dll

Tags: java, dll, launch4j, javaw

I try to execute a jar.

`java.exe` is wrapper system dll files. so it can use native library.

But `javaw.exe` is not wrapper system dll or path..

`java -jar somejar.jar` correctly works.

But `javaw -jar somejar.jar` isn't working with dll library..

I must use `javaw.exe`.

Because `java.exe` is executed on console windows.

I don't want to popup console windows... I want to execute only my jar.

How can I use `javaw.exe`? or `java.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is an [option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) that you can set the system property with the javaw command. This way you can set the library path.

> -Dproperty=value Set a system property value. If value is a string that contains spaces, you must enclose the string in double quotes:
>           java -Dfoo="some string" SomeClass

You can see some details [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp) also (Point-#4).